# when i want to fetch data from table i got this error. can anyone help me?

Tags: hibernate

Error:
The method get(Class, Serializable) in the type Session is not applicable for the arguments (Class, int)?

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Configuration config = new Configuration().configure();
        SessionFactory factory = config.buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = factory.openSession();
        Transaction trx = session.beginTransaction();
        Sample sample = new Sample();
        sample = (Sample)session.get(Sample.class, 1);
        trx.commit();
        System.out.println("success");
        session.close();
    }
}

public class Sample {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: As stated in the error, the second parameter cannot be an Integer only but it has to be previously defined as Serializable. My best advice is to write a generic implementation for this normal queries as [this class](https://github.com/luciomartinez/hibernate/blob/master/Registro/src/registro/dao/GenericDaoImpl.java). If you're willing to try a solution in-line may be using the `serialize` method from [SerializationUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/SerializationUtils.html) class could work but not sure about that.

Comment: If this does work for you, i'd write down a bit cleaner on an answer later :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
...
sample = (Sample)session.get(Sample.class, new Integer(1));
...
```

instead of simple int.

Comment: Thank u streetturtle